# PHP to insert into file

Tags: php

I am using `php` to insert something into a file. I want that what i want to insert get inserted in file after 5 lines from top.

Like Below is a `.txt` file example.

> This is 1st line
>
> This is 2nd line
>
> This is 3rd line
>
> This is 4th line
>
> This is 5th line
>
> ```
> Here should be my content inserted with PHP
> Here is my previous content inserted with PHP
> ```
>
> This is some other text in file.

Well i am able to insert but not after lines i want. I am using below php code to insert:-

```
<?php
$file = ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sitemap.txt' );;
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= "http://www.onlinedealsindia.in/deal/SOME-UNIQUE-LINK\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106719/trying-to-insert-text-into-a-file-above-a-certain-line

Comment: Not able to understand. Need a good and simple code.

Comment: How about `$contents = str_replace($contents, $fifth_line_text, $fifth_line_text . PHP_EOL . $content_to_insert)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $test = "http://www.onlinedealsindia.in/deal/SOME-UNIQUE-LINK";
    $file = ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sitemap.txt' );
    $contents = explode("\n", file_get_contents($file), 6);
    file_put_contents($file, $contents[0]."\n".$contents[1]."\n".$contents[2]."\n".$contents[3]."\n".$contents[4]."\n".$test."\n".$contents[5]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use file to get the file as an array of lines, then change the line you need, and rewrite the whole data back to the file.

```
<?php
$file = ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sitemap.txt' );;
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= "http://www.onlinedealsindia.in/deal/SOME-UNIQUE-LINK\n";

$line_i_need_to_change = 5-1; // Since line array starts from 0

$lines = file( $file , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );

$lines[$line_i_need_to_change] = $current.$lines[$line_i_need_to_change];

//I noticed that $current have \n that helps to move the old data to next line 

file_put_contents( $file , implode( "\n", $lines ) );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`SKIP_LINES` says how many lines you want to skip.
The new content that you want to add should be an array so it's handled properly.

The function [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) does the job.

**OLD:**

```
<?php
define('SKIP_LINES', 5); 
$file = 'existing.txt';

// read existing file into array
$existing = file($file);

// fill new array with existing data to SKIP_LINES
$new = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= SKIP_LINES; $i++)
    $new[] = array_shift($existing);

// this is the new content that you want to add (as array)                                                                   
$addThis = file("newcontent.txt");

// merge skipped 5 lines, new content, and the rest of the existing file
$new = array_merge($new, $addThis, $existing);

// write the new file
file_put_contents($file, $new);
```

**Edit:**

**NEW** version adjusted to your thingy.

```
<?php
define('SKIP_LINES', 5); 

$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sitemap.txt';                                                                                               

// read existing file into array
$existing = file($file);

// add this array with the new content
$addThis = [ "http://www.onlinedealsindia.in/deal/SOME-UNIQUE-LINK\n" ];

/* splice array after SKIP_LINES. $existing now has Line 1-5 and $addThis
   $new contains all lines after the 5th (SKIP_LINES) line */
$new = array_splice($existing, SKIP_LINES, 0, $addThis);

// merge 5 lines with the new content and the other lines
$new = array_merge($existing, $new);

// write the new file
file_put_contents($file, $new);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
```

});
var url="http://localhost/larasampleold/";

$(function() {

var formgenre =$("#productForm");

formgenre.validate({
// ignore: ':hidden:not([class~=selectized]),:hidden > .selectized, .selectize-control .selectize-input input',

rules: {

```
// banner_title:{

//    required:true,

  // // trimWhiteSpace:true,

//   remote:
//             {

//                 global: false,

//                 url: base_url +"/title_exist",

//                 type: "post",

//                 data:
//                         {
//                             name: function () {
  
//                                 return $('#banner_title').val();

//                             }
//                         }
//             }, 
    
// },

// seo_keyword:{

//     required:true

// },
```

//      image:{

//     extension: "jpeg,jpg,png,bmp",

//     filesize:  20000000,

//   },

```
},
messages: {

//     banner_title: {

//     required: "Enter the banner title.",

//      remote: "Banner title is already exist.",

// },

//     seo_keyword: {
  
//         required: "Enter seo keyword.",
        
//     }

},
```

focusInvalid: true,

```
invalidHandler: function (form, validator) 
{
    if (!validator.numberOfInvalids())
        
        return;

    validator.errorList[0].element.focus();

},
```

//errorElement: "span",
//errorClass: "help-block help-block-error",
errorElement: "p",

```
        errorClass: "invalid-feedback",

errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

  

           
   
        error.insertAfter(element);
        
           
},
highlight: function (e) {

$(e).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");

},
unhighlight: function (e) {

$(e).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");

},
success: function (e) {

e.closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");

},

submitHandler: function (form) {

if (formgenre.valid() == true) {
  
        // if(maxSize())
        // {
var formData = new FormData(formgenre[0]);
    
    $.ajax({
    url: url +'employee/insert',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
    if (response.rs) {
    //formcity[0].reset();
       window.location= url +'employee';
    } else {
    
    (response.errType == 'v') ? formgenre.prepend(showAlert('Required', response.msg)) : technoNotify('', response.msg, 'error');
    }
        
    } ,
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var $errmsg = '<p>Status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '</p><p>Error Thrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p>';
 
    console.log($errmsg);
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
    
    $('#axloader').show();
    },
    complete: function () {
    $('#axloader').hide();
    
    },
    timeout: 100000
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
    console.log('Failed from timeout');
    }
    });
    
     
    }
//}
    return false;
    }
    
    
    });

});
```

//file upload

if($request->hasFile('photo'))
{

```
        $file=$request->file('photo');

        $extension=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
       

        $filename="employee-".strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:S')).'.'.$extension;

        $file->move(base_path('public/employee'),$filename);

        $stud->photo=$filename;
      
    }
```

Comment: please be clear in answering question using HOW-TO write codes, not too much line-spaces.

Answer (score 0):

//header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

.dataTables_processing {

    top: 64px !important;

    z-index: 11000 !important;

}
```

//del data

$(document).on('click','.del_data',function(){

```
     var id=$(this).attr('id');
     
     $.ajax({

           type:'delete',

           url: url + '/' + id,

           dataType:'JSON',

           success:function(data)

           {

              alert(data.message);

              bustype_tb.ajax.reload();

           }

        });

  });
```

//show data

$data=EmployeeModel::find($id);

```
    return view('employee.view',compact('data')) ;
```

//destroy

$stud=EmployeeModel::find($id)->delete();

```
    return response()->json(['message'=>'deleted successfully'], 200);
```

//index

if($request->ajax())

```
    {

        $data = EmployeeModel::latest()->get();

        return DataTables::of($data)

                    ->addIndexColumn()
                   
                   ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                    $button = '<a href="empEdit/'.$data->id.'" > <button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit_data edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button></a>';

                    $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$data->id.'" class="del_data delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>';
                    $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="dropdown-item" href="empView/'.$data->id.'" role="menuitem">
                    <i class="icon md-eye text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i><button type="button" name="view" id="'.$data->id.'" class=" view btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</button></a>';


                    return $button;

                })

                ->rawColumns(['action'])

                ->make(true);

    }

    return view('employee.list');
```

//ajax datatable

var bustype_tb = '';

$(function () {

bustype_tb = $('#studtable').DataTable({

```
    processing: true,

    serverSide: true,

     ajax:{

       url: "{{ route('student.index') }}",

   },

    columns: [
           
             {
                data: 'DT_RowIndex', 

                name: 'DT_RowIndex',

                 orderable: false,

                 searchable: false

                 },

             {

                 data: 'sname', 

                 name: 'sname' 

                 },

             {

                 data: 'fname',

                  name: 'fname'

                   },

             {

                 data: 'dob',

                  name: 'dob'

                   },

         
             {

                data: 'action',

                 name: 'action', 

                 orderable: false

           },

          ],

 });


 bustype_tb.ajax.reload();
```

});